# More than 150 active threads in java application

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, webserver, jmx

I have a web service running on tomcat. I have configured 30 request threads. The service is working fine. The unusual thing is that the number of threads JMX is displaying are more than 150. My application is not forking any threads in the application java code. I am unable to know what could be the reason for this? I couldn't find anything on google and SO as well..

Comment: There are plenty of threads besides the ones that you start, depending on the environment. Look at the names of the threads (for example with `jstack`) and you'll wonder no more.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman. That was prompt!!
Can you please provide some examples on what could be these threads. I am concerned on this because if there really are 150+ threads in my application that could mean that they are sharing the time slice of the CPU and thus somewhat delaying my application API's response times.

Comment: You'll know better when you see them yourself. 150 sounds a bit high, but it's no use speculating before observing.

Comment: So I checked the thread dump from jstack. I found ~171 threads in Blocked state and ~134 threads in IN_NATIVE state. But I can't make out anything from the stack trace of these threads. The IN_NATIVE ones shows epollWait(...) in the stack trace and the BLOCKED ones are in Unsafe.park()..
One more thing, right now this service is sitting idle not serving any traffic.

Comment: Any further insight or pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the threads are blocked so they won't be taking any time off the CPU for one. If there are so many threads in native, you're probably using the Tomcat Native Library? You could have oversized threadpools configured or something along those lines. The `visualvm` suggestion is good too. It's included in the JDK and you can observe what's happening better.

Comment: Sure. I will take at look at visualvm. What is the rational behind "you're probably using the Tomcat Native Library"? The thread pool to tomcat is configured at 30.

Comment: Well, that may be a false assumption, but "regular" Tomcat shouldn't use too much native code and the native library would explain at least some of the large amount of IN_NATIVE threads.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like VisualVM (https://visualvm.java.net/) will give you a complete list of all running threads in your current process.